# How to organize different content to be on left and right side of page without using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm very new to html/css so I need a bit of help with organizing my page. I wanted to have the "Join my newsletter" to the left of the page; with the "Want commissions" on the right. I already have Flexbox in use on another page, and am uncertain if it can be used again in a way that won't mess up it's original use (It took forever for me to figure out and don't want to go through that again).

Here is my Snippet,

```css
form {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<h3> Want to be informed of new content? </h3>

  <p> Then join my newsletter and never miss out again! </p>
  
  <form><!-- Start Form -->
   <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName">
   
   <label for="email">Email:</label>
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
   
   <p>I would like more information about:</p>
   <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="newart" id="newart" value="newart" class="chkbx">New Art</li>  
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="announ" id="announ" value="announ" class="chkbx">Announcements</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="commi" id="commi" value="commi" class="chkbx">Commissions</li>
   </ul>
   
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
   <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Form" class="btn">
    
  </form>

    <h3> Want a commission?</h3>
  
  <p>Contact me @ </p> <a href ="mailto:kaijumydude@gmail.com">KaijuMyDude@gmail.com</a> 
  <p> or DM me on social media </p> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/kaijumydude/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/instaicon.png" style=" width: 5%;" alt="Instagram logo"></a>
```

Here is the CSS for the ul and li that I have in use for another page that is interfering with the checkboxes on this page

```
/*About List Stuff*/
ul {
margin: 0 auto;                  
width: 1200px;
padding-left: 0;               
font-size: 0; 
}

 li{
font-size: 18px;                 
list-style-type: none;
width: 150px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
margin: 15px auto;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want flexbox, you could always use inline-block.

Comment: You should train that flexbox skills. It will save you a lot of time on the future.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the sections you want positioned in divs and use a wrapper to give them inline-block. Then position them left and right. Try this code:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <h3> Want to be informed of new content? </h3>
    <p> Then join my newsletter and never miss out again! </p>
    <form><!-- Start Form -->
        <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
        <p>I would like more information about:</p>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="newart" id="newart" value="newart" class="chkbx">New Art</li>  
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="announ" id="announ" value="announ" class="chkbx">Announcements</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="commi" id="commi" value="commi" class="chkbx">Commissions</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
        <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Form" class="btn">
    </form>
  </div>
<div class="right">
<h3> Want a commission?</h3>
    <p>Contact me @ </p> <a href ="mailto:kaijumydude@gmail.com">KaijuMyDude@gmail.com</a> 
    <p> or DM me on social media </p> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/kaijumydude/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/instaicon.png" style=" width: 5%;" alt="Instagram logo"></a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
/*Form Stuff*/
form {
float: right;
}

.wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
}

.left{
  float: left;
}

.right{
  float: right;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/z9v6cwoa/9/

Comment: This really helps, but I have one issue that I didn't notice until now. Is there a way I can make the ul/li as well as some header and paragraph tags on this page separate from ones on other pages? I have them centered on others, but don't want them to be here. That's the only thing in that way of your advice working I believe.

Comment: Of course, which parts do you want moved? If you're operating off of one master CSS file, and you want to specify just those elements, give the elements you want to be different unique id's and target them that way.

Comment: See this example - I used and ID to make the header (`<h3>`) red. -- https://jsfiddle.net/z9v6cwoa/18/

Comment: I've run into the issue of getting the checkboxes and text to align left. All the right content is stuck to the right, but under where it needs to be and I am unsure if the checkboxes are whats blocking it from aligning properly, or they aren't going where they need to be.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. All the text and checkboxes look left-aligned to me. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Oh, I see, when you shrink the window. I think this is why flexbox is generally the preferred option for this type of thing, but if you really don't want to use it, i'll look into what options you have.

Comment: Try making your `.right` class `float: left;. You'll probably have to adjust the margins to make it spaced the way you want, but it should appear directly below if it runs out of room in the same row.

Comment: Here's a crude example of what I think you're going for. Play with the values to get it to your liking. -- https://jsfiddle.net/z9v6cwoa/38/

Comment: I added the code I have for my other page that is messing up the checkboxes to the bottom of my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I know learning flexbox can be hard, but please consider a flexbox solution:

**HTML**

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__section">
    <h2>Form</h2>
    ** other content **
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper__section">
    <h2>Want a commission?</h2>
    ** other content **
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}
.wrapper__section {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

If you're worried that a certain section might not work as expected, consider adding one wrapper-`<div>` with a regular `display: block` so it does not behave as a flex-child. It looks like you're a bit fed up with flexbox. That would be a pity, keep trying and you'll learn!

Comment: It's not that I'm worried about using flexbox, I'm just worried that adding anything new will effect what I'm using it for.

Comment: Well try it ;) And if it does not work, you can always for the time being add another wrapper to reset flex behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

use `width:100%`

put one `div` in `left` and another one in `right`

```css
form {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
<span style="float:left">
  <h3> Want to be informed of new content? </h3>

  <p> Then join my newsletter and never miss out again! </p>

  <form><!-- Start Form -->
    <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName">

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">

    <p>I would like more information about:</p>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="newart" id="newart" value="newart" class="chkbx">New Art</li>  
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="announ" id="announ" value="announ" class="chkbx">Announcements</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="commi" id="commi" value="commi" class="chkbx">Commissions</li>
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
    <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Form" class="btn">

  </form>
</span>

<span style="float:right">

    <h3> Want a commission?</h3>

    <p>Contact me @ </p> <a href ="mailto:kaijumydude@gmail.com">KaijuMyDude@gmail.com</a> 
    <p> or DM me on social media </p> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/kaijumydude/" target="_blank"><img src="Images/instaicon.png" style=" width: 5%;" alt="Instagram logo"></a>
</span>
</div>
```